# How to control the expanding of the expandablelist in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need to expand the expandedlistview only on click on a button in that list i want the list to get expanded. can anyone please guide me on how i can do it. i tried setenable on expandedlist but it dosent work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post a code snippet and ask help from there.

Comment: its a normal question like how to make a toast message. i felt i dont need a snippet for that. anyways i will do it for every of my question from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ExpandedListView expandedlist;

expandedlist.setenable(true);
expandedlist.setenable(false);
```

Extremly sorry guys, i didnt check properly

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try below like that

```
ExpandableListView Exlist;

Exlist.expandGroup(0);
Exlist.expandGroup(1);
```

Comment: its throwing exception when i tried that. Im using layout inflaters.